# Joining MS DB to Oracle DB using SSRS

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, ssms, lookup

I have two datasets, one in SSMS and one in Oracle I'm trying to combine through SSRS. Technically I have two questions regarding the results I'm getting.

Dataset 1:

`DataSet1 - Sales - MS
Part       Location      Transaction_date         QTY_SOLD
1234       New York      06/01/2017                1
1235       New York      06/01/2017               4`

`Dataset 2 - Returns - Oracle
Part       Location      Purchase_Date            QTY_RTN       Reason`
1235      New york      06/01/2017               2             Broken`

What I'm wanting to get:

`Part      Location      Date                QTY_SOLD     QTY_RTN     Reason
1234       New York      06/01/2017          1            NULL        NULL
1235       New York      06/01/2017          4            2           Broken`

I have lookup expressions set to join on part, location, date for qty_rtn and reason columns.

Part one, 1234 with no returns does not show up. The first dataset should return ~1400 items. The second dataset should return the same theoretically, but since that info is manually entered the purchase_date does not always match the transaction_date (this is fine. half the purpose of this is to find those mistakes and get someone to go back and correct the data). When I run the query, I get ~400 items.

Part two, when I do a preview from within Studio, the MS and Oracle data shows up. When I pull from the web interface, only the MS data shows up. I've checked that the credentials on both sides are correct and have the correct connection strings as well.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was broken, but I wound up deleting and re-creating the report from scratch and it works with all the data as it's supposed to. Web interface is also not missing data.